# How to redirect standard/error output to file whil using Run command?

Tags: vba, wsh

I am using following code:

```
cmd = """" & "C:/node/executable/path/node.exe" & """" & " " & """" & "C:/path/to/script.js" & """" & " > " & """" & "C:/path/to/output.txt" & """"
WshShell.Run cmd, 0, False
```

cmd looks like this:

```
"C:/node/executable/path/node.exe" "C:/path/to/script.js" > "C:/path/to/output.txt"
```

This script works (it starts in background) but output is never redirected to a file (file does not appear). What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The redirection operator (">") is a `cmd.exe` shell feature. The `node.exe` process needs to be launched by a `cmd.exe` process:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

cmd = "cmd.exe /c ""C:\node\executable\path\node.exe""  ""C:\path\to\script.js"" > ""C:\path\to\output.txt"""

WshShell.Run cmd, 0, False
```